# React (typescript) hooks order of execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm struggling with a language switching feature. The home page of my app at / should pickup a previously localstorage setting, `'preferredLanguage'`, or pick up a default language from `navigator.language` if no preference is set. It should be able to handle lang routes `/cat` and `/es` that set that preference and the page language and redirect to /.

It looks like this:

A useLang hook that sets the preferred and switches lang

```js
export const useLang = (lang: string) => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Setting lang to ${lang}`);
    localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', lang);
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    document.title = t('PageTitle');
  }, [])

}
```

App.tsx

```js
const SetLang = ({ lang }: {lang: string}) => {
  useLang(lang);
  return (
    <Redirect to='/'/>
  )
}

export const App = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const targetLang = localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage') ?? navigator.language.includes("es") ? "es" : "cat";

  // Debug: 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Preferred: ${localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage')}, Default: ${navigator.language.includes("es") ? "es" : "cat"}, Will set lang to ${targetLang}`);
  }, []);

  useLang(targetLang); // Y U NO WORK?

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/es" >
          <SetLang lang="es" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/cat" >
          <SetLang lang="cat" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePage/>
        </Route>
        // ...etc
      </Switch>
    <Router>
  )
```

Executing gives the following logging:

```
Preferred: es, Default: es, Will set lang to es App.tsx:25
Setting lang to es
```

Then I go to /cat and expect it to switch to catalan but a subsequent call occurs switching it back to es:

```
Setting lang to cat 
Preferred: cat, Default: es, Will set lang to es
Setting lang to es
```

I'm confused. Something is not behaving as I expect. I see that the expression `localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage') ?? navigator.language.includes("es") ? "es" : "cat";` should resolve to 'cat' if it is present in localStorage as the logging suggests. After page reloading, I check localStorage and yields 'es', as expected from the last  call to useLang with the unintended 'es'.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using hooks correctly. Now I defined a function within it and returned it, confining effectful code into that function.

```js
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export const useLang = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

  const setLang = (lang?: string) => {
    const preferredLang = localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage')
    const defaultLang = navigator.language.includes("es") ? "es" : "cat";
    const targetLang = preferredLang ?? defaultLang;

    console.log(`Preferred: ${localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage')}, Default: ${navigator.language.includes("es") ? "es" : "cat"}, Will set lang to ${targetLang}`);

    if(lang){
      localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', lang);
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }else{
      localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', targetLang);
      i18n.changeLanguage(targetLang);
    }
    document.title = t('PageTitle');
  }

  return {setLang}

}
```

```js
export const App = () => {
  const {setLang} = useLang();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setLang(); // TY!
  }, []);

  return (...)
}
```

Note that even though preferredLang and defaultLang were updating (previously they were just expressions), targetLang was not since it was closured over the hook. Thus yielding the weird situation resulting in the `Preferred: cat, Default: es, Will set lang to es` line (weird since it suggested that `'cat' ?? 'es'` resolved to `'es'`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your deps for `useLang` should include `lang` also. I'm pretty sure that you get a warning about this actually. Try changing it to this:

```
export const useLang = (lang: string) => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Setting lang to ${lang}`);
    localStorage.setItem('preferredLanguage', lang);
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    document.title = t('PageTitle');
  }, [lang])

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not work. It seems weird to me to put a parameter in the dependencies array?